# How to select DISTINCT with Datatables 1.10.4

Tags: php, sql, datatable

I have two columns named col1 and col2 in my database, and I would like to do

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM name_table
```

Is there a way to do this with DataTables 1.10.4 ? I haven't found the answer in the forums.

I use the SSP class via this url : http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: You can't just add distinct to the query? If you're using SSP you have to do that from the server side.

Comment: HI. Check the URL. It's a bit complicated to make the request to the SSP class. But I need to achieve my goals

Comment: DataTables isn't an SQL server.

Comment: I use DataTables on a daily basis. You have to do any data processing on the server side if you are using server side processing. You can't make the datatable filter anything on the client side.

Comment: Yes , okay . But I do not understand how to explain to my PHP to do SELECT DISTINCT . Where do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Perhaps it will help someone.

It needs to change the SSP class from :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '.implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'));
```

To

```
SELECT DISTINCT '.implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'));
```

So create another SSP class with this parameter or extend the SSP class with a function named distinct() for example.